# Find out how much percent one string contains in another

Tags: c#, algorithm, string

I need to find out how much percentage or chars does one string contains into another string.
I've tried Levenshtein Distance but that algorithm returns how much char's are needed to be change for the strings to be equal.
Can some one help?
I need it in c# but that's not so important.

The answer code:
    public double LongestCommonSubsequence(string s1, string s2)
    {
        //if either string is empty, the length must be 0
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s1) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(s2))
            return 0;

```
    int[,] num = new int[s1.Length, s2.Length];  //2D array
    char letter1;
    char letter2;

    //Actual algorithm
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)
    {
        letter1 = s1[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < s2.Length; j++)
        {
            letter2 = s2[j];

            if (letter1 == letter2)
            {
                if ((i == 0) || (j == 0))
                    num[i, j] = 1;
                else
                    num[i, j] = 1 + num[i - 1, j - 1];
            }
            else
            {
                if ((i == 0) && (j == 0))
                    num[i, j] = 0;
                else if ((i == 0) && !(j == 0))   //First ith element
                    num[i, j] = Math.Max(0, num[i, j - 1]);
                else if (!(i == 0) && (j == 0))   //First jth element
                    num[i, j] = Math.Max(num[i - 1, j], 0);
                else // if (!(i == 0) && !(j == 0))
                    num[i, j] = Math.Max(num[i - 1, j], num[i, j - 1]);
            }
        }//end j
    }//end i
    return (s2.Length - (double)num[s1.Length - 1, s2.Length - 1]) / s1.Length * 100; 
} //end LongestCommonSubsequence
```

Comment: Does the order of the characters matter?

Comment: you are missing examples. the question is very vague.

Comment: My bad for not writing examples, ok there they are :)
Ex:
string a = John Malkovich;
string b = Joahn Mulkovich;
The difference between these strings is 2 chars or they are the same 84.6 percents.

Ex. 2:
string a = John Malkovich;
string b = Jonh Malkovich;
They are the same 84.6 percent

A hope I this will help.

Comment: How about `"hcivoklaM nhoJ"`, the reverse of that `"John Malkovich"`. Is that `0%` similar or is this `84.6%` similar as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might want the [longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) which is the basis for diff algorithms. Unfortunately this problem is NP-hard which means there is no efficient (polynomial time) solution. The Wikipedia page has some suggestions.

Comment: Here the problem only consider 2 strings, therefore it can be done in quadratic time.

Comment: Write now I'm testing this, so I'll write the results in a few minutes.

Comment: Yep the tests went well, thanks.
I'll edit the Question with the c# algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Uhh... can't you just use the number of characters that need to change then?

```
(length(destination)-changed_character_count)/ length(source)
```

EDIT: based on the revised question, treat both strings as sets, compute the set intersection, and base the percentage off the size of that set and the source string as a set.

Comment: I need how much one string contains into another, for example "Ivan" in "This is Ivan Jovanov" is contained 100%.

Comment: @Pece: the Levenshtein distance would tell you that. That's why you compare the length of the destination string minus the size of the edits to the length of the source string. In your test case, it should end up being 100% because you don't actually delete any characters from the source string.

Comment: The problem in this is if I compare "Ivan" with "Ivaxxxn" is that if I use: "(length(destination)-changed_character_count)/ length(source)" it will return 100%

Comment: That's an additional constraint you should probably specify.